# Can AWS LAMBDA Web API authenticate by middleware if you send jwt token in the header

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a .net core 3.1 web api authenticated by jwt in the middle ware pipline.Works fine. I converted the web api to a lambda web api by adding a aws Lambda entry class and published into aws with an API Gateway in front

All the endpoints without Authorization attribute worked fine.
All the endpoints with Authorization attribute gets 401.
All request has a jwt Authorization Bearer token header

One endpoint without Authorization attribute reponses with all the headers converted to a string.From that i can see the request's jwt is getting thru to the endpoint.

1.Why isnt the endpoint giving me 401 even tho there is a token?

2.Does AWS lambda or the API getway not pass the header direstly?

3.Do I need to configure the api geteway to send the header to the lamdbda endpoint?

4.Can Lambda authenticate by pipline like a normal web api?

Another solution was to use authorization Lambda with the API GETWAY.
If I use authorization Lambda does that mean my end point wont need the authorization attriibutes any more because it done in the getway?

JWT is generated and authenticated by Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

It works I finally figured the reason. Its so awesome you can have Web api as a Lambda in aws. I can now spend less money in AWS.